# jquery blur and unblur part of image

Tags: jquery, css

I have two photos one blured and one not. I want to drag `div` to see unblured area. I have a example here: https://jsfiddle.net/78knkqw2/2/

```
 $( function() {
    $( "#draggable" ).draggable(            
    {
        containment: "parent",
        cursor: "move", 
        cursorAt: { top: 150, left: 100 },

        drag: function(){
          var position_top = $(this).position().top ;
          var position_left = $(this).position().left;


         console.log("top:"+position_top+" left:"+position_left);

            if(position_top<=0)
                position_top = position_top;
            else
                position_top = '-'+position_top;

            if(position_left<=0)
                position_left = position_left;
            else
                position_left = '-'+position_left;

                $(this).css('background-position', position_left+'px '+position_top+'px');

        },

        stop: function( event, ui ) {
          var position_top = $(this).position().top ;
          var position_left = $(this).position().left;

         console.log("top:"+position_top+" left:"+position_left);

            if(position_top<=0)
                position_top = position_top;
            else
                position_top = '-'+position_top;

            if(position_left<=0)
                position_left = position_left;
            else
                position_left = '-'+position_left;

                $(this).css('background-position', position_left+'px '+position_top+'px');

        }

        }

    );

  } );
```

The problem is the background postion change is like jumping the area.
I want the effect working as smooth.

Comment: here the example : https://jsfiddle.net/78knkqw2/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JQuery drag callback is slightly delayed, that's why it's jumping.
Always try to implement the functionality yourself, something like this.

```
var draggable = $( "#draggable" )

draggable.mousedown(startDrag)

var drag_mouseX
var drag_mouseY
var drag_elementX
var drag_elementY

function startDrag(e){
    //remember current mouse position
    drag_mouseX = e.clientX
  drag_mouseY = e.clientY

  //remember current element position
  var pos = draggable.position()
  drag_elementX = pos.left
  drag_elementY = pos.top

  // add mousemove and stop listener
    $(document).on('mousemove',dragMove)
  $(document).on('mouseup',stopDrag)
}

function dragMove(e){
    // subtract initial mouse position from current mouse position and add the elements initial position
    var posX = e.clientX - drag_mouseX + drag_elementX
  var posY = e.clientY - drag_mouseY + drag_elementY
  var bgPos = (-posX)+'px '+(-posY)+'px'
    draggable.css({top:posY,left:posX,backgroundPosition:bgPos})
}

function stopDrag(){
 // remove listeners -> stop dragging
    $(document).off('mousemove',dragMove)
  $(document).off('mouseup',stopDrag)
}
```

Comment: yeah its working! thank you man .but have one problem the drag div  going out of container ... how to fix it to stay inside the container ?

Comment: update: iam updating the code you can see https://jsfiddle.net/78knkqw2/6/